# Почему нельзя удалять из коллекции в цикле for?

Tags: java, коллекции

Почему нельзя удалять из коллекции в цикле fori, я читал что возникает исключение и это небезопасно. Но можно объяснение почему именно так? Спасибо

Comment: Может быть ConcurrentModificationException потому что при удалении будут смещаться индексы элементов

Comment: А можно поподробнее как они будут смещаться и почему?

Comment: @LittleBudda предположим у вас есть последовательно `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` Индексация начинается с нуля, поэтому у элемента со значением `3` индекс - `2`. Если вы удалите первый элемент, получите последовательность `[2, 3, 4, 5]`. Какой теперь индекс у элемента со значением `3`?

Comment: @LittleBudda используйте итератор для удаления элементов в массиве\

Comment: Как раз таки `fori` использовать можно, но нужно уменьшать `i` после удаления элемента, а вот `foreach` использовать нельзя, он только для чтения.

Comment: А можно более детально объяснить почему for each использовать нельзя, почему возникнет исключение?

Comment: Потому что foreach использует неявный итератор, который не любит постороннего вмешательства в коллекцию, пока он итерирует её. Но есть мнение, что конкурентные коллекции лишены этого недостатка, но при этом не дают никакой гарантии, что будут перебраны все элементы в случае внешних изменений коллекции.