# Почему нельзя удалять элементы из коллекции в цикле for-each?

Tags: java, коллекции, foreach

Почему нельзя удалять из коллекции в цикле for-each?

Я читал, что возникает исключение и это небезопасно. Но можно объяснить, почему именно так?

Comment: Как мне кажется, коллекция начинается с обычного массива указателей на элементы. При удалении массив "сжимается", а итератор это не учитывает, ибо не может (ведь удалиться может как элемент до текущего указателя, так и после - в этих случаях надо вести себя по-разному, во втором случае изменить предел итерирования, а в первом уменьшить счётчик текущей позиции).

Comment: @Akina и то и то вполне алгоритмизуется. Должны быть более веские причины.

Comment: это же уже было https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1008896/199253?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ConcurrentModificationException и Хешмап](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/835695/concurrentmodificationexception-%d0%b8-%d0%a5%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bf) - Я уже объяснял, что и как работает.

Answer (score 1):

При попытке удаления конкретного элемента коллекции через for-each произойдет ошибка. Например, при удалении:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:859)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:831)
    at Cat.main(Cat.java:25)
```

Общее правило, которое нужно запомнить:
нельзя проводить одновременно итерацию (перебор) коллекции и изменение ее элементов.

Иначе получается серьезная ошибка. Это из-за того, что когда элемент удален, размер `List` уменьшается и индексы элементов меняются. И необходим более усовершенствованный вариант "пробегания" по элементам.

Стоит понимать, что цикл `for` не является итератором.

Для более глубокого изучения необходимо изучить в спецификации метод `.iterator()`

Так же, в цикле for-each мы работаем с итерационной переменной, а не с элементом массива. Это так же важный момент.

Comment: В простейшем случае, это решается итерированием от конца к началу, тогда текущие элементы можно хоть все удалять. Но, тогда нельзя добавлять элементы на ходу (а при итерировании от начала к концу - можно).

Comment: так же в цикле for each мы работаем с итерационной переменной, а не с элементом массива. Это так же важный момент